# Xcode 12. copy swift standard libraries into... error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, react-native

I have a Mac Mini M1, and I'm facing this issue: `Build input file cannot be found... (in target 'appname' from project 'appname')`, this is the copy Swift standard libaries into 'appname.app' error...

Can build on real device, can archive, can do everything but the simulator doesn't work. I tried all workaround what founded on different forums but nothing works. This is a react-native project. If somebody got this issue and found a solution please help.

Comment: The question has been answered already. Due to a bug in SO app, I can not copy the link. Use search.

Comment: I tried everything what was suggest in context of this issue, nothing works. I wrote this, maybe somebody has more informationr.

Comment: Any solutions for this?